# How replicate-ignore-db OR replicate-ignore-table works internally?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, database-administration, binary-log

In MySQL replication we have replication filters:

```
replicate-ignore-db
replicate-ignore-table
```

These filters are used to ignore the database / table to replication on slave server.
During the creation of relay log, slave server check the rules and ignore the db/table that exist in these options and don't write it in relay logs.

So my question is:
Is the slave server read binary log and ignore the db/table at master server only OR all logs transfer to slave server and then slave ignore those db/tables ?

Because my concern is I have large amount of binary log because of only one big audit table. I don't want to replicate it but want to create binary log of it.
Now there is a issue of large binary log transfer over the network. So i want to know is the whole binary log transfer on slave and then check the filters OR filters checked on master server and then transfer only required logs ?

Thanks